# Data Wrangling for Modeling in R

Tags: r, modeling, dataset

I have a data set (original version, `# A tibble: 33,478 x 12`) of the form similar to the attached picture, and partial data:

[image]

`dput(head(canals2, n=10))`

```
 structure(list(Site = c(1, 2, 4, 11, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), 
    `Sample Date` = c("2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", 
    "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", 
    "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004"), `Analysis code` = c("NH3", "NH3", 
    "NH3", "Chl a", "Chl a", "Chl a", "NH3", "Chl a", "NH3", 
    "NH3"), Analysis = c("Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Chlorophyll a", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen"), Result = c(0.068, 0.07, 0.014, 1.31, 
    1.39, 1.95, 0.247, 1.46, 0.113, 0.17), Units = c("mg/L", 
    "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/L", "mg/m3", 
    "mg/L", "mg/L")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to try to predict, for instance, "Chlorophyll a" from "Ammonia-Nitrogen" using a linear model (say, using the `lm()` function). `lm()` takes column names as inputs for 'formula', yet this dataset was generated very differently. I should be using the values in the `Results` column for each analysis, but I can't seem to find a good way of organizing my data as such.

So far, I tried splitting the data by analysis, with the intention of creating a new dataframe for each analysis, then replacing the `Result` with the name of the analysis selected in that dataframe.  Here is the function I used (ran it on the main data set, which is why it contains more analysis names):

`analysis_list = unique(canals$Analysis)`

`> analysis_list`

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L1Fu.png) "Ammonia-Nitrogen"        "Chlorophyll a"           "Fecal Coliform"
[4] "Specific Conductance"    "Copper"                  "Dissolved Oxygen"
[7] "E Coli"                  "Enterococci"             "Nitrite + Nitrate"
[10] "Ortho-Phosphate"         "pH"                      "Salinity"
[13] "Temperature"             "Total Kjeldahl Nitrogen" "Total Nitrogen"
[16] "Total Phosphorus"        "Turbidity"

```
split_analyses <- function()
  canals_byAnalysis <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)
  for (i in 1:17) {
    analysis <- analysis_list[i]
    updated_analysis <- canals %>% 
                    subset(Analysis == analysis, 
                    select = -c(`Analysis code`))
    canals_byAnalysis[[i]] <- updated_analysis
  }

split_analyses()
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work as expected, and I had many issues merging the tables I created. I tried other ways as well, but I am getting nowhere. Is anyone willing to offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you may need to answer first is:

How do the observations (of different measurements and units) relate to each other. What is the primary key of your dataset, that identifies 1 unique observation?

From the sample data that you provided it looks like neither '`Sample Date`' nor '`Analysis Code`' provide sufficient information to identifiy 1 unique observation, so '`Site`' might be the variable to look into?

Once you answered that question, you can look into `pivot_longer()` [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) which will most likely help you to transform your dataset into the format you need for `lm()`.

Comment: I think it's [pivot_wider](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) the function the OP may need?